# Why does the setUserVisibleHint called before onCreateView in Fragment?

Tags: android, fragment

I have searched many post on stackoverflow but didn't get the reason behind this.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation ([link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#setUserVisibleHint%28boolean%29)), this function is used by the system to prioritize; therefore you want the system to know which priority has this fragment before you ask the system to create the view.

Comment: So, what is the alternative?

Comment: Hi @AzureusSme, I'm not sure what you mean with "an alternative" but the alternative would be to use the default (which is true). Think as a little improvement in performance that you will do if set this value as false on all the hidden fragments (the system would create all that are not overriding or have this value to true).

Comment: I ended using the `newInstance` and `onSaveInstanceState` methods to initialize and save my data. I still use `setUserVisibleHint` to send hits with Google Analytics. Its working fine.